# Jhipster / Oracle connectivity steps ? dev database?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, jhipster

I tried many ways to generate Jhipster app with oracle as DEV_DATABASE_TYPE.
still not succeed and i can't find the steps to follow.

Tested with Jhipster 11g2 and 12c2, non of it worked.

Steps i followed : 
Generate and app using JDL fil : app.jdl

```
application {
  config {
    applicationType monolith,
    baseName jhipsterSampleApplication,
    packageName io.company.crud,
    authenticationType jwt,
    databaseType sql,
    prodDatabaseType oracle,
    devDatabaseType oracle,
    buildTool maven,
    searchEngine false,
    testFrameworks [gatling, protractor],
    clientFramework angularX,
    clientTheme Litera,
    clientThemeVariant Light,
    enableTranslation true,
    nativeLanguage en,
    languages [ en, fr ]
  }
  entities *
}
```

Then i update these files : application-dev.yml and pom.xml

```
spring:
  profiles: dev
  datasource:
    driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    dataSourceClassName: oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl
    username: rest_test
    password: rest_test

  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
    database: ORACLE
    openInView: false
    show_sql: true
    generate-ddl: false
    hibernate:
        ddl-auto: none
        naming-strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
    properties:
        hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: true
        hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
        hibernate.generate_statistics: false
        hibernate.cache.region.factory_class: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory
```

I tried to delete this line from app.jdl :

```
prodDatabaseType oracle,
```

and i got an error saying :  Only 'h2Memory', 'h2Disk', 'mysql' are allowed as devDatabaseType

Does anyone have a clear process to follow, in order to generate an app with Oracle DB ?

Thank you

Comment: their docs say they do not support 11, so i'd stick to trying 12...

Comment: Thats what i did, trying on 12c
but the online generator start.jhipster.tech/ say : please follow our documentation to use the oracle proprietary driver. 
Still can't find this documentation nor the driver mentioned. do they mean JDBC ?

Comment: I didn't see a lot either other than if you have questions post them here, i saw one item on github, your config looks similar

Comment: Why did you try to delete "prodDatabaseType oracle," line from app.jdl (this is used only for generation)? Where are the errors you're trying to fix?

Comment: The problem is i can't connect Jhipster to Oracle. 
there's no clear steps to follow 

I tried to delete, just so i can test the reason behind the issue

Comment: Did you start Oracle from docker generated file? Nothing different from  other databases. Are you beginning in Jhipster and/or Spring Boot?

Comment: yes i'm discovering i, i'm a beginner.
i didn't used docker for it. i should try it

Comment: ps : i installed Oracle 12c locally on my windows laptop

Comment: When using generated docker-compose file src/main/docker/oracle.yml you are assured that everything is well configured   versus  what you did manually on your PC. https://www.jhipster.tech/docker-compose/#4  If you're a beginner why  chosing Oracle?

Comment: sorry for my late reply due to corona quaratine etc .. Thank you for this explanatio, i'll make sur to test it again using docker compose. 
Oracle was the choice of the company

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was resolved here : stackoverflow.com/questions/60640151/jhipster-and-oracle-11gr2 thank you all